# Insert text in EPPLUS RichText

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using EPPLUS to write to excel file, and I am using multi-styling for some cells, the issue is that I want to insert text in a specific location in these cells.

```
worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum].RichText.Text.Insert(index, string);
```

Turns out that the above line of code will try to insert the string in the indexth element not the indexth character.

I also tried this:

```
 worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum].RichText..Text.Insert(index,string);
```

No string is inserted using this too.

I am thinking of calculating the length of each RichText's element and adding a new element to the RichText where the length of previous elements = index, but I am searching for a better solution.

Comment: This question seems a bit similar to the one you asked 2 hours after this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139224/epplus-is-duplicating-strings-on-insert

Comment: no, this is different question, I could find a way to solve this.
the other question is about strange behaviour in EPPLUS, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because Insert returns a new string in which your specified string is inserted a the specified index position in this instance so you would have to do:

```
worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum].RichText.Text = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum].RichText.Text.Insert(index,yourstring);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but for some cases (RichText has more than one element and I am inserting string to first element) I am getting second element duplicated!
strange!

Comment: @YahyaHussein could you provide an example please ?

Comment: worksheet.Cells[rownum, column].RichText.Add("first ");
                    worksheet.Cells[rownum , column].RichText.Add("second");
                    worksheet.Cells[rownum, column].RichText.Text = worksheet.Cells[rownum, column].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");

--- Result: first Insertedsecondsecond

Comment: @YahyaHussein I've found a workaround:worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add("first ");
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add("second");
               worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText[1].Text = worksheet.Cells[1,1].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");   result: first Insertedsecond

Comment: what if worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text.Count()<6?

Comment: @YahyaHussein it will throw System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException like for  var test = "toto";
                test.Insert(6, "tutu");  it is by design so you will have to test string length     if (worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText[1].Text.Length>=6) btw better use with linq :  if (worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Last().Text.Length>=6)
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Last().Text = worksheet.Cells[1,1].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149358/discussion-between-xavave-and-yahya-hussein).