# EPPLUS is duplicating strings on insert

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to insert text into RichText, when the index of the inserted string is at the end of an element the next element gets duplicated!

Here is an example:

```
worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Add("first ");
worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Add(" second");
worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Text = worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");
```

Result: "first Insertedsecondsecond"

Is this normal behavior? because I am expecting to get:

"first Inserted second"

Comment: Do you need to assign the return value of `Insert()` back to the `.Text` property of the cell? Couldn't you just call `Insert()` on its own? (sorry not that familiar with eeplus). What does it return?

Comment: yes, it does not affect the string itself, it returns the updated string.

Comment: What does changing `worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Text = worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");` to just `worksheet.Cells[rownum + 100, column].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");` do?

Comment: What did you expect? And why use 'insert' instead of 'add'?

Comment: Did you use a nuget? if so, what version? or a download of the codeplex source? if so, step into the 3rd line to see if the bug is really related to the epplus lib or expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this to simulate your issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage ep = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet 1");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].IsRichText = true;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add("first ");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add(" second");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text = ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");

        Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells[1, 1].Text); // shows your bug
    }
}
```

and this gives an array of 2 items on `ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText`

where the first one gives your desired value.
[image]

this does not fix it...

```
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add("first ");
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add(" second");
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text = ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text.Insert(6, "Inserted");
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.RemoveAt(ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Count - 1);
Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells[1, 1].Text);
```

The problem is in the richtextcollection having a second item. which should not be there.

```
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Remove(ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Last());
```

even throws an Exception!

The only solution I can come up with is to clear the array of RichTextCollection first.

```
string curText = ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text;
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Clear(); // remove previous nodes
ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text = curText.Insert(6, "Inserted");
```

Full sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage ep = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet 1");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].IsRichText = true;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add("first ");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add(" second");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Add(" third");
        string curText = ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Clear();
        ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText.Text = curText.Insert(6, "Inserted");

        Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells[1, 1].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Insert does not update the text, it returns the updated text instead.